# Why is the value null?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I have a discord currency bot and whenever I type a certain command it makes the players money turn to null in my .json file that stores data. here is some of the code

```
{"468477297440063499549810913822244895":{"userData":null,"money":1000},"553378693968560128549810913822244895":{"money":1000},"468477297440063499":{"userData":953,"money":null},
```

Whenever I execute a command that gives the target user money and subtracts it from the user it turns the value of the target user "null"

the code that adds/subtracts the amount

```
let moneyAmount = parseInt(args[1]);

{code here}

      userData[message.author.id] = {
        userData: userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].money -= moneyAmount
        };

      userData[targetUser.id + message.guild.id] = {
        userData: userData[targetUser.id].money += moneyAmount
      };
```

If someone can tell me how to make it so it doesn't turn null and actually adds the money that would be great.

Comment: I made a small mistake I posted the answer below

Answer (score 1):

stupid me, if anyone else comes across this error change

```
 userData[targetUser.id + message.guild.id] = {
        userData: userData[targetUser.id + message.guild.id].money += moneyAmount
      };
```

to

```
 userData[targetUser.id] = {
        userData: userData[targetUser.id].money += moneyAmount
      };
```

I put message.guild.id in the wrong place